# AI for the Dice game FARKLE

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, dice

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have a dice game called Farkle.  The game is working great as a Two Player game.  Now I want to implement an AI for a One Player game.  Basically all I want it so if the current Dice score is >= lets say 300 to pass the dice back to the Human Player.  There are a few other things I would like it to look for such as if all the dice have been used and all 6 dice can be rolled again.

I am new to the entire Java/Android world, so really don't know where to begin or look for any example for Dice AI examples.  I have found a few for Poker, but I think they are way more complex then I need or for that matter can even understand.  Any ideas?

BTW... I would be willing to send the source code for the Game to anyone that is willing and or able to help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What functionalities does your game have that cannot be done with let's say just if/else statements?

Comment: I'm not sure how to be more specific, but I'll try. After the Human player finishes I want it to check to see for either a Human Player (Regular 2 player game) or AI.  If AI then to Roll the dice and "SOME HOW", pick the correct dice, if the possible score is >= 300 then pass it back to player 1 if not roll again etc...  and I'm not saying it can't be done with if/else statements.  It's very possible that, that may be the best option.  This is why I ask... I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I don't know any AI library that could help you. In addition I had to actually read the farkle rules to understand the concept and how AI could be integrated into that. So 2 options come into my mind that you however will have to implement yourself:
1.Use a neural network. The network will be trained using maybe [backpropagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation). As an error you could maybe use the difference of the 6 dices (that maybe be modelled by 6 different output neurons) sum from 300. If you search a bit I don't believe you will find it difficult to find a java library or source code examples.
2.Use genetic algorithms. For this actually there is a quite nice library [JGAP](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/). The chromosomes will be the result of rolling all 6 dice and the fitness function would be their score.
Of course both of the routes mentioned above are pretty generic and may not be very accurate. I am afraid that you will have to get familiar with certain AI concepts/algorithms. The farkle game is not that popular to have an AI package itself (like chess for example), so I believe you will have to implement things on your own (maybe using some libraries). Hope this helps.

Comment: I am NOWHERE near educated in programming enough to even to begin to understand any of that.  I looked at the 2 links you provided and I was a like a deer in headlights.  I can see I have a VERY Long road ahead of me.  Thanks for taking the time to at least answer my question.

Comment: You are welcome, although I believe you can also say thanks in a bit more practical way...Anyway.I wish you good luck along the AI path :)